# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - deploy by CodePipeline not working - health status - Severe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have created pipeline in CodePipeline. Pipelien is runnig fine, every stage are succeeded.

Even deploy stage is in state succeeded, but there is issue with running app on Elastic Beanstalk. I don't know why, mabe by Enhanced health authorization.

When i upload .war file manually to Elastic Beanstalk, app is runnig well. But when CodePipeline is uploading .war file to Elastic Beanstalk its not working.

My buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo In the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn clean package
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/myapp.war
  discard-paths: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this is because a wrong artifact format is deployed. You can check this by going to the S3 bucket the pipeline is using and checking what artifact is produced. I anyways recommend that you upload a zip file and not a single war. This will allow you to use an .ebextensions file and deploy more than one war, if needed. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-multiple-war-files.html) for details.

You can deploy a zip file like this:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo In the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn clean package
      - mkdir build-output
      - cp target/myapp.war build-output/myapp.war
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - build-output/**/*
    - base-directory: build-output*
```

Comment: Hej,

Thank you for answer.

I used your code. Now I have in S3 zip file with folder build-output and .war file inside, but the issue is the same.

Elastic Beanstalk have status Health - Severe

I think it could be a problem with permissions, but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: Make sure that the beanstalk service role has the permission to access the S3 bucket.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk application version tab contains every my deploy. What i see there are .zip files from S3.
I tried deploy .zip file manually and it doesnt work. It looks like Elastic Beanstalk get .zip file from S3 and dont know how to unzip this file.

Do you know how to tell Elastic Beanstalk, to unzip file and then deploy .war file ?

Comment: Clicking the file in Application version should download it, however with no proper extension. You will need to add the .ZIP extension yourself. Try also base-directory directive.